# Best way to convert a data:image/gif into a binary PNG or JPEG?

Tags: javascript, png, gif

Is there a way to convert a gif (using only JavaScript & no external libraries) into a binary PNG or JPEG to save to the disk?

Example:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhOgA6AIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAOgA6AAAC/4yPqcvtD6OctNqLs968+w+G4gKU5nkqKGCsLju9q4q2chrDTGnzAe7b6SJBEgxosjmKEN/sNyw6jzUoZYpESKm9pDXXnQrF0Cy47GUezE/1ksrmfrHpYRNeV87lbfvDveanN2h0JRgopHVIeHdD9ugIOOaoBxk5gpmpWcnnR6YIWgHJuEcTahjmRYOE04WK1prQFxvb6OnCGVn7pxrYl3qZQ4tHZ4ooWpVbp7ZlYYkrGyWH8fx0WrpJusW6uMEszW0YrDiOJk4ZXb77xu7bvd1tnOje7nr2iz18LUE3utd87BU+e+EC3qsCj2AvSQ36dQJGLM/BOBArfuH3DpxEfyGv5qXiBBJZMI4G1zXUFfIbuXjZWrp8CTOmzJk0a9p0UAAAOw==
```

Comment: Why not save it as a GIF? Or is the question *explicitly* about a format conversion?

Comment: Yeah, so I need to get it into the format of PNG or JPG. It must be in one of those formats. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using the atob thing, that doesn't work. I've tried using base64toBlob converters and get an error message saying: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded." So I am not sure if I am doing something wrong, or if the string isn't base64 (but it says it is).